# How to update the confetti to look like it blast from behind image to the front and fall down

Tags: javascript

I need the confetti to blast or pop from top and behind the image and falling down.

Please advise

The file that import confetti.js will have the following code.

```
const initConfetti = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < confettiCount; i++) {
    confetti.push({
      color: colors[Math.floor(randomRange(0, colors.length))],
      dimensions: {
        x: randomRange(10, 50),
        y: randomRange(10, 50)
      },
      position: {
        x: randomRange(0, canvas.width),
        y: canvas.height,
      },
      rotation: randomRange(0, 2 * Math.PI),
      scale: { x: 1, y: 1 },
      velocity: {
        x: randomRange(-25, 25),
        y: randomRange(0, -50)
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Is the reference to "confetti.js" [this npm package](https://github.com/Agezao/confetti-js)? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77164910/edit) to the question to clarify (see [ask]).